# jqGrid - tell if row was selected or deselected with multiselect on

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have the following grid:

```
        $(function(){

        $("#poGrid").jqGrid({
            url:'URL',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:[],
            pager: '#poPager',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            sortname: 'orderID',
            sortorder: 'ASC',
            jsonReader : { repeatitems: false },
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: '&nbsp;',
            multiselect: true,
            height: "100%",

            colModel :[

                {name:'orderID', label:'Order ID', width:80, align: 'center'},
                {name:'orderName', label:'Order Name', width:250},
                {name:'countTotal', label:'Count Total', width:80},
                {name:'orderTotal', label:'Order Total', width:80},
                {name:'orderDate', label:'Order Date', width:100}

            ],

                onSelectRow: function(id){

                    var grid = jQuery('#poGrid');
                    var sel_row = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    var sel_id = grid.jqGrid('getCell', sel_row, 'orderID');

                    setOrderIDs(id,sel_id);

                }

        });
```

I am just trying to figure out if the row that triggered the onSelectRow was selected or deselected before I run the `setOrderIDs` function. If it was trigged by a deselect I do not want to run the function.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very easy. You should test the value of the second boolean parameter of [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events): `status`

```
onSelectRow: function (id, status) {
    if (status) {
        // row is selected
    }
}
```